# Different behaviour in PWA installation on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I’m actually making a PWA. When i’m installing the application from Google Chrome 67 on Android 8 i can notice two different behaviours :

- When i’m offline, the application is fully installed as a PWA and launch in standalone mode.
- When i’m online, the application is not installed. Chrome just adds a shortcut to my website which launch into chrome (not in standalone mode).

My manifest.json seems to be properly filled with the required directives (see below) :

```
{
  "name": "Candy Sugar",
  "short_name": "Sugar",
  "description": "A candy Sugar",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icons": [
    {
        "src": "assets/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "assets/favicons/android-chrome-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "assets/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "assets/favicons/android-chrome-144x144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "background_color": "#00777d",
  "theme_color": "#00777d",
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
}
```

I’m surprised by these behaviours and i don’t really know what i’m doing wrong. Can someone please help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your URL with the Chrome Lighthouse audit tools?
If under Passed Audits, you see **User can be prompted to Install the Web App**
You should be good to install

From my testing:
If you are offline, only a normal shortcut will be added
If you are online, a WebApk will be installed

If you a have a URL you can share, I can check for you

Comment: I've tested my app with Lighthouse, the **User can be prompted to Install the Web App** pass the check.

For now i haven't put the app in production but soon. For my case i was on the localhost, i've tried over https and that's works like you describe.

Thanks for the reply, i reply as soon the app is online for the URL.

Comment: If you want something fast and free for testing, try glitch.me - I load all of my build files into one GitHub folder and glitch imports from there in seconds. see; https://a2hs.glitch.me